# How to completely destroy a windows form while leaving it.?

Tags: vb.net

I am pretty much new to visual basic and I have this thing bragging me.
I have two forms in my windows application on selecting some properties in first form and them clicking on proceed then second form loads. I have written some code to execute while second form is loading according to the type of radio button checked on first form.

Below is the code for Load event on second form.

```
         `If Selectdisplay.rdbtnmps.Checked = True Then
        LoadFromExcelForRDIToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        LoadFromExcelForTIToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        Label1.Text = "Prediction of MPS in SINTER PLANT 4"
        Chart1.Series(2).Enabled = False
        Chart1.Series(3).Enabled = False
        Chart1.Series(4).Enabled = False
        Chart1.Series(5).Enabled = False
    ElseIf Selectdisplay.rdbtnti.Checked = True Then
        LoadFromExcelToolStripMenuItem1.Visible = False
        LoadFromExcelForRDIToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        Label1.Text = "Prediction of TI in SINTER PLANT 4"
        Chart1.Series(0).Enabled = False
        Chart1.Series(1).Enabled = False
        Chart1.Series(4).Enabled = False
        Chart1.Series(5).Enabled = False`
```

"select display" being the first form. so now when I exit the second form and return to the first form the properties I set above when the second form is loading for first time are being retained and I want them to reset in another words I want to destroy the second form completely when I exit it so that I can load it freshly by checking different radio buttons in first form.

Thank you for reading
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: while you are working on the second form, what happens to the first form? do both forms coexist? the first form is hidden? the second form shows like a dialog-box such that the user cannot go to form1 until form2 is closed?

Comment: second form shows like a dialog-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you said in the comments that the second form shows like a modal dialog. i would prefer in form1:

```
Sub Button1_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using frm2 = new Form2()
        frm2.ShowDialog()
    End Using
End Sub
```

also, in form2, i would refrain from `If Selectdisplay.rdbtnti.Checked = True Then` type calls. dont reference a form by its static name. rather use actual references. So in form2, i would have:

```
Public SelectdisplayForm as Form
```

modifying the `Button1_Click code`:

```
Sub Button1_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using frm2 = new Form2()

        ' --- NOTE THIS LINE ---
        frm2.SelectdisplayForm = me

        frm2.ShowDialog()
    End Using
End Sub
```

and then in form2, whenever you want to reference anything from form1, use the local field (variable) not the form class name.

```
                 |--|
 If SelectdisplayForm.rdbtnmps.Checked = True Then
                 |--|
     do something..
                     |--|
 ElseIf SelectdisplayForm.rdbtnti.Checked = True Then
                     |--|

     do other thing..

 End if
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking in to the `FormClosing` event (documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).

So in your second form add a handler like this:

```
Protected Sub SecondForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    'add code to change selected radio buttons etc.

End Sub
```

This event handler will be called as the form is closing. You could also use the `FormClosed` event in much the same way (documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx).

Comment: yeah this is fine..is there anything like `set me = nothing` or `set secondform = nothing` without closing the entire program

Comment: I mean when you exit entire program(including "select display" which is the start up form) everything will reset right.? so I want that without closing first form but closing only second one should do..!! Thanks..

Comment: Please add the code that creates and shows the second form from your "select display" form to your question.

Comment: yeah bro..you're on right track it was in the code of "second form from your "select display" " .I changed it and problem now is resolved. Thank you for your quick reply.. actually your links directed me in the right direction..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just to call form.Close() before accessing the document.

```
Selectdisplay.Close()
If Selectdisplay.rdbtnmps.Checked = True Then
....
ElseIf Selectdisplay.rdbtnti.Checked = True Then
....
end if
```

Comment: selectdisplay is the "startup form" so if you add this form close event in load_event of second form entire program will close

Comment: What's the name of the second form ? Thats the one you need to close before accessing it with the new info. In VB it will create a new form behind the scenes when you access it for the first time. Thats why this strange behavior is seen.